# Как рекурсивно создать двунаправленный список зная только количество элементов, Java

Tags: java, рекурсия, структуры-данных, списки, связывание-данных

Есть DDS DoubleNode, которая является двунаправленным списком:

```
public class DoubleNode {
public int value;
public DoubleNode prev;
public DoubleNode next;

public DoubleNode(int value, DoubleNode prev, DoubleNode next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.prev = prev;
    this.next = next;
}
```

а вот что я пытаюсь сделать, так это построить такую Node, зная только количество элементов в ней (значения элементов выбираются случайно). При всем при этом построить хочу рекурсивно, сваял вот такой метод:

```
    public static DoubleNode doubleNodeGenRec (int length) {
    return (length == 0) ? null : new DoubleNode((int)(Math.random()*10), null, doubleNodeGenRnd(--length));
}
```

как новому элементу передать ссылку на `DoubleNode prev;`?

выходит, что строится Node в одну сторону, т.к. в методе туда передается просто null, и в результате выходит просто связанный список. чем заменить этот null?

Comment: А зачем рекурсивно? Построение списков рекурсивно — прямой путь к переполнению стека.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public DoubleNode(int value) {
  this.value = value;
}

public static DoubleNode doubleNodeGen(int length) {
  return doubleNodeGenRec(length, null);
}

private static DoubleNode doubleNodeGenRec(int length, DoubleNode prev) {
  if (length == 0) {
    return null;
  }

  int value = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
  DoubleNode node = new DoubleNode(value);
  node.prev = prev;
  node.next = doubleNodeGenRec(length - 1, node);
  return node;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло )) решение на вопрос отвечает! При этом я думал, что возможно создать решение, при котором аргументом метода будет только int ))) выходит что нельзя, все равно нужно передавать значение предыдущей Node в метод, а жаль. посидел пол часика поковырял ваш код, единственное что смог сократить, так это 1 строчка и первый конструктор. Спасибо большое, за код, разъяснение и потраченное время! з.ы. Снимаю шляпу.

Comment: з.ы. Math.random() * 10 нужно заключить в () а то приведение все время "0" выдает )), но то такое .. мелочи, еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Ага, поправил. Вобще лучше не жертвовать читабельностью кода ради его компактности.